# Jquery apply bg for just for one <td> not the whole column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the function table.on, right now if i drop a cell from table 2 to table 1,  the whole column gets green

js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L3Lhw7jk/5/

`tr td:nth-child(2)` whole column get green, I would like just make the `td` where I drop not the whole `tr td:nth-child(2)`

css:

```
  tr.highlight td {
    background-color: #D0ECE7 !important;
  }

  td.member-highlight {
    background-color: #73C6B6 !important;
  }
```

it is something on this if:

```
 if (r[0].length > 0) {
        $row.parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $row.addClass('highlight');

        var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
        members.filter(':not(:has(input))').addClass('member-highlight');
        members.find('input').addClass('border-highlight');
    }
```

**var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');**

that make apply the whole green in the whole column

```
table.on('mousedown', 'tbody tr', function() {
    var $row = $(this);

    var r = table.rows(function(i, data) {
        return data.member == $row.children().first().text();
    });

    if (r[0].length > 0) {
        $row.parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $row.addClass('highlight');

        var members = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
        members.filter(':not(:has(input))').addClass('member-highlight');
        members.find('input').addClass('border-highlight');
    }

    rowCache.push({
        row: r
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks pete, so how i should apply this in my code? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi check this one example [worked example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Lhw7jk/6/)

```
    function mouseUp(event) {
    var names = $('#example tr td:nth-child(2)');
    var ctrl = $(document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).filter('#example tr td:nth-child(2),input.border-highlight');

    if (ctrl.length > 0 && rowCache.length > 0) {
        var el = rowCache[0];
        var data = el.row.data();

        if (data.length > 0) {
            if (ctrl.is('input'))
                ctrl.val(data[0].name);
            else
                ctrl.text(data[0].name);

            el.row.remove().draw();

            ctrl.addClass('name-highlight');

            //names.removeClass('name-highlight');
            names.find('input').removeClass('border-highlight');
        }
    }

    rowCache = [];
}
```

Comment: cool, very nice thank you, can I highlight the td too? before I drop? like was before but just taking 1 td instead of all column ? thank you.

Comment: can you help me apply this effect on this fiddle?  you need click edit first to be able to drop , http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/47/  thank you